# Exercise Before/During Airplane Rides To Prevent Deep Vein Thrombosis

Tags: exercise

I have read about deep vein thrombosis on long airplane rides. Although I am in fairly decent physical shape, it's my understanding that this can happen to healthy individuals as well. Various articles I've read state that certain stretching and exercising can help to alleviate some of these problems. However, many of the articles don't really give specifics as to what these stretches or exercises might be.

What stretches or exercises, either before, during or after the flight, can I perform to help prevent this condition? Obviously, confined space is an issue so something like burpees in the lavatory or sprints down the aisle aren't going to do.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.everydayhealth.com/news/long-flight-bed-rest-easy-exercises-prevent-blood-clots/

I don't know what you're looking up, but I found this article literally within 2 seconds of looking on Google. I looked over it and it has some good exercises that you can do during the flight. I highly doubt you have to go to the extremes of burpees or sprinting to get your blood flowing.

Comment: Thanks. I swear I used Google to look for that exact thing. Must have just been having a bad night. Thanks